# C# WinForms Generate Designer Code from Dynamic Form At Runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to find a way to generate bare bones windows form designer code from a dynamically created form at run time so I can then load that designer code into visual studio and have an exact replica of the form that was running (the UI anyways).

We have a .NET application that generates forms dynamically in a very convoluted manner (in house custom serialization coming from a Java app) so there is no actual windows forms code for these.

I have read and played with the DesignSurface stuff shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx

Which makes it seem like this is possible.  This works for creating a form from scratch, but I cant figure out how I would create a DesignSurface from an already running form so I can then generate the code.

I could use Reflection and try to generate a decent InitializeComponent() function myself, but seems like there is a way to do this.  Otherwise will have to do this by hand for a lot of forms.

Is there possibly an easier way to do this, or a free/commercial app that may do what I need?

Comment: You're in for a challenge, friend.

Comment: `will have to do this by hand for a lot of forms` - If you intend to put these forms into a designer, then the "dynamic" nature of the entire thing is put into question. Why are you receiving stuff from a java application and building UIs dynamically if the UI is not really dynamic? You should consider ditching winforms and using proper technology (WPF) which will allow you to take the serialized data coming from the java application and use it as a Data Source for the UI, while keeping the UI in a declarative design-time created fashion...

Comment: allowing highly dynamic UI behavior without "constructing" the UI from scratch at runtime.

Comment: @HighCore they are dynamic in the sense that they are created dynamically, but they are explicitly constructed (in a custom Java editor).  Its part of a legacy system and thats how it ended up.

Comment: @joshjje if you're doing any sort of rework, forget winforms and use current technology. That will result in a much greater ease of development and scalability, and probably a much better end result as well.